# Are the coordinates in WINDOWPOS on WM_WINDOWPOSCHANGED in parent coordinates or screen coordinates?

Tags: winapi

Quick and simple one this time. I have a subclassed tab control that handles `WM_WINDOWPOSCHANGED` to, when not `SWP_NOSIZE`, resize its content. It passes the `WINDOWPOS` `lParam`'s `cx` and `cy` fields to `TCM_ADJUSTRECT` to get the content rect size.

I need to do this on command as well (after changing tabs, say). However, I can't just do a dummy resize to the same size; even with an explicit `SetWindowPos()`, real Windows seems to add `SWP_NOSIZE` itself if the size doesn't change. So I want to write the analogous code to my `WM_WINDOWPOSCHANGED` handler.

My question is: what coordinate system are the coordinates given to `WM_WINDOWPOSCHANGED` given in, parent coordinates or screen coordinates? `GetWindowRect()` returns screen coordinates, so I'd like to know if I need to convert the coordinates to get the same values that I would get in `WM_WINDOWPOSCHANGED`. The documentation for `WM_WINDOWPOSCHANGED` doesn't say; neither does the documentation for `WINDOWPOS`.

Thanks.

Comment: There is `ScreenToClient(hwnd, &point)` where point is the x and y screen coordinates from `WINDOWPOS, GetWindowRect, GetCursorPos`, etc. `hwnd` is the handle of the specific window, dialog, or dialog control.

Comment: Right, you're suggesting the answer is screen coordinates, then. Just to be sure, though: I'm not looking for client coordinates, but I'll rephrase the question as if I was: if I am going from the `WINDOWPOS` in `WM_WINDOWPOCHANGED` to client, do I use `ScreenToClient(hwnd)` or `MapWindowRect(GetParent(hwnd), hwnd)`?

Comment: Yes, the answer is always in screen coordinates. And you need to find client coordinates to move child windows.

Comment: All right, thanks. I thought the point of `TCM_ADJUSTRECT` was to get a client rect?

Comment: I think `TCM_ADJUSTRECT` returns relative values, it doesn't need conversion. Also `WINDOWPOS` cx/cy are width and height, they are the same in both screen and client coordinates. It's only the x/y value which need conversion. Some calls like `ON_WM_MOUSEMOVE` return x/y client coordinates. Also another options is using `SWP_NOMOVE` flag, that lets you use `SetWindowPos` to change size without moving the top-left corner.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`WINDOWPOS, GetWindowRect, GetCursorPos`, etc. give screen coordinates. When you use `SetWindowPos` you have to supply coordinates in relation to parent. This is straight forward for main window and popup windows which use screen coordinates. For moving child windows, you can use `ScreenToClient` and `ClientToScreen` for conversion.

For example, this will find the coordinates of OK button in relation to top-left corner of dialog box:

```
RECT rcOK; 
HWND hitem = ::GetDlgItem(m_hWnd, IDOK);
GetWndRect(rcOK, hitem, m_hWnd);

void GetWndRect(RECT &rect, HWND item, HWND parent)
{
    ::GetWindowRect(item, &rect);//screen coordinates of OK button

    POINT offset{ 0 };
    ClientToScreen(parent, &offset); //Top-left (0,0) of client area of dialog -> screen coordinates

    rect.left -= offset.x;
    rect.right -= offset.x;
    rect.top -= offset.y;
    rect.bottom -= offset.y;
    //client coordinates of OK button in relation to Dialog's Top-Right
}
```

Now we can move up the OK button by 10px:

```
rc.top -= 10;
rc.bottom -= 10;
::SetWindowPos(hitem, 0, rc.left, rc.top, 0, 0, SWP_NOSIZE);
```